# Windows 8 System Refresh missing start menu tiles

Tags: windows-8

Having done a System Refresh on Windows 8 it now seems to have lost all the standard (default user?) start menu tiles, even Desktop tile is missing.  Any suggestions how to get these back again.

After the System Refresh SFC was run for safety and I was quite surprised to discover that it found and corrected a fair number of items.  Clearly System Refresh does not quite work properly.

We have two identically named 'Start Menu' directories, in:

- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows

At least one of these must be a symlink I guess, they are actually:

- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AllUsers
- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu

Which one is correct or should they both be there?

Edit:
I feel sure that the directory

- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows

should not contain both

- 'Start Menu' real directory

and

- 'Start Menu' symlink - pointing to
  C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AllUsers

but question is which is rogue and which is correct?  And how have we ended up with two, could roaming profiles be involved in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the store, click on "My Apps" and select "Apps not installed on this PC" and select all apps you want to install:

[image]

[image]

**Source:**

http://www.howtogeek.com/127274/how-to-restore-uninstalled-modern-ui-apps-that-ship-with-windows-8/

Comment: Unfortunately 'Windows Store' is one of the missing tiles.

Comment: Can you still use the search charm to get to the store?

Comment: No unfortunately not.

Comment: was sfc able to fix all issues? If not, run DISM: http://blogs.technet.com/b/joscon/archive/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012.aspx

Comment: Yes SFC fixed everything and now runs clean

Comment: try the app troubleshooter: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271185

Comment: but this is not just apps that are missing there is no Desktop tile either

Comment: There are two 'Start Menu' directories in the same place:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu & 
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu (symlink pointing to: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AllUsers)

Question is which is the rogue one and which is correct?

Comment: I don't have a path C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AllUsers. The correct path is **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs**

Comment: How interesting, thanks magicandre1981.  Sound like then C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\AllUsers is the rogue directory that I should delete.  I wonder where that came from could it be related to Roaming User Profiles I wonder.

Comment: I have no idea where this folder comes from.

Comment: Think I might have some idea where this has come from.  This machine did at one time have Folder Redirection enabled via a GPO but that is now switched off.  Might it be that Folder Redirection created the AllUsers (Start Menu) symlink and deleted the original 'Start menu'.  I then suspect that System Refresh has a bug in that it recreates that 'Start menu' folder which then exists alongside the 'Start menu' symlink.